# Display custom messages in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well, this may be a silly question, but since I'm very new to codeigniter, I have no idea how to do this.

What I want to do is, display my custom errors messages whenever I want(such as login failed, Post Successfully published...etc.) in the front end (On login-form-view, write-post-view...etc.).

Earlier, when I was using just PHP (no frameworks), I stored those messages in a `$_SESSION` global variable and echo them in the front end pages. But here, I hope CodeIgniter comes with a better solution.

Comment: In `codeigniter` you can use `$this->session->set_flashdata('success','Your message')` for success and replace `success` with `failure` that's it

Comment: Ok thanks, here failure means ? is it just a string ?

Comment: That's for differentiating those success and failure calls nothing else you can use your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use session flash data it only works on redirect

For example

```
public function index() {
  $this->load->library('form_validation');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {

    $this->load->view('login');

  } else {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have logged on');
    redirect('success_controller');
  }
}
```

On Success Page View

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success')) { ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Thanks.. when I was trying this, the first redirect doesn't show the message. I have to press the login button again to see the message. Why is that ?

Comment: @TharinduLucky I do not know why because you have not added any code to your main post

Answer (score 2):

You can use flash data in codeigniter. It will clear automatically.

**Controller :**

```
//syntax => $this->session->set_flashdata('name', 'your message');

$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Post Successfully published.');
```

**View :**

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');`

Refer http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter has something called `FlashData`. Flash data will bring through a session variable that will exist for the next request, then clear itself after.

In CodeIgniter 3, you set flash data like this:

```
$this->session->mark_as_flash(array('item', 'item2'));
```

or:

```
$this->session->mark_as_flash('item');
```

Alternatively, you can use `set_flashdata`, which will work with previous versions of CodeIgniter:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

You can view flashdata by doing this:

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

If you want to preserve flash data through an additional request, you can use `keep_flashdata`:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
```

FlashData uses the session library, so make sure it's loaded in either the library autoloader, or in the controller using it.

[FlashData Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flashdata#flashdata)

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you can use like

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Your message here');
redirect('controller_name/method_name');
```

In your View you can use like

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
```